# Aligning instances to normal + facing forward with geometry nodes

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

I have a leather strap mesh that's deformed with two curve modifiers (Curve A for the strap wrapping around a hook, and Curve B for the general shape on a body).

I instance a top stitch mesh on certain vertices which are part of a vertex group. By using the setup below, the instances are aligned to the normals properly, however, they are not "facing forward" as you can see on the left end where the mesh wraps around.

I figured I could use the tangents of curve A to align the instances in the forward direction. It seems to work, but I cannot figure out how I would set the factor for each instance.

[image]

If I get rid of the Curve B modifier and just have the mesh follow Curve A in a straight fashion, everything works. But as soon as I throw a 2nd curve modifier in the mix that alters the general orientation of the mesh, it breaks.

[image]

Comment: Using a "realize instances" node at the end of my setup and placing the 2nd curve modifier (Curve.001) below the geometry nodes modifier solves my problem. I was hoping to avoid this for performance reasons, so if anyone knows of a better way to achieve this, I'd appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizing the instances and placing the 2nd curve modifier below the geometry nodes solved the problem.